# Twitter bootstrap: anchor links

Tags: html, twitter, hyperlink, anchor, twitter-bootstrap

I hope this is a very simple question (I'm only using bootstrap since today), but how do I show a new page when someone clicks on a navbar item?

For example, I have this code:

```
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#directions">Getting there</a></li>
                <li><a href="#theme">Japanese theme</a></li>
                <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rsvp">RSVP</a></li>
            </ul>
```

But how do I switch page when someone clicks on say, "Photos"?

I don't want to refresh the page and I'd prefer to do it all using AJAX.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Bootstrap is client-side. You need to tell us what you use server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alp says, Twitter bootstrap doesn't handle this functionality. I use PHP server side and AJAX client side to show/hide new content.